# how can I view deleted records in an ibd file?

Tags: mariadb, recovery, wordpress, mariadb-10.6

I'm in a situation with a wordpress site where a table `wp_options` keeps increasing in filesystem size really fast even though it only has 10000 records and we have to constantly optimize it to reduce the usage.

It's my understanding that when records are constantly deleted / inserted they are not actually deleted from the ibd file but they're kind of soft-deleted.

Thus the filesystem size on the file actually increases constantly reaching even 500G within 2 days.

In order to fix the issue I need to actually see what is being written / deleted from the table constantly to find possible plugins that might be affecting it.

I can safely assume it's wordpress transients however I can't say with certainty which type of transient is causing this bloat without examining the data.

So in order to find this out I'm looking for ways to read the soft-deleted data from the bloated ibd file.

I've tried a couple of tools like undrop-for-innodb but it's not yielding any results.

Any ideas how I can read the mass of deleted data that's occupying the filesystem space?

```
Server version: 10.6.15-MariaDB-1:10.6.15+maria~ubu2004 mariadb.org binary distribution
```

Comment: I think this was a bug that has been fixed. Are you on the latest 10.6 release? (another release out very soon (days)).

Comment: Hi, I'm on 10.6.15

Comment: [no fixes seem relevant in 10.6.16](https://jira.mariadb.org/issues/?jql=fixVersion%20%253D10.6.16%20and%20component%20%253D%20%22Storage%20Engine%20-%20InnoDB%22). I'd suggest `ALTER TABLE wp_options FORCE` to get the size down, should take as much time as writing those existing 10k records. Look at `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` at the and  "History list length" [information_schema.INNODB_TRX](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/information-schema-innodb_trx-table/) on transactions open on the table. If it continues [create a bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org).

Comment: History list length is 2317 currently but not sure what to check with INNODB_TRX . Isn't there a way to limit how much extra space the tables will use for history compared to the actual data they need to maintain??

Comment: I've monitored a lot more of wordpress databases and they all have quite a chunk of deleted data occupying space in the wp_options table. i've opened a bug report as I think it's a general issue not site specific https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-32663

Answer (score 0):

Some plugins are quite abusive with `wp_options`.  There is no way to do what you are asking about, but I would try

```
SELECT * FROM wp_options
    ORDER BY RAND()  LIMIT 50;
```

It may be evident that many of the rows are being used by one plugin.

If not obvious in the output, repeat the query a time or two to get some more random stuff and/or catch the plugin doing its naughtiness.

This plugin may help the table be more efficient, but won't help with abuse or size:  [*WP Index Improvements*](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/)

Note:  By making queries to that table faster, it may decrease (dramatically?) the "history list length".

Comment: Unfortunately upon further observation it's not just wordpress. I've just noticed it on magento session tables and in cron_schedule history tables as well. I even manually deleted 3.5m rows and it didn't make a dent in the filesystem size after days. Eventually the deleted data should have been released

Comment: For big deletes:  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

Comment: The db table is also increasing in filesize on the filesystem (not actual size) even with normal processing of regular transactions where expired sessions are deleted. I just happened to notice it after deleting a big chunk due to a bug, but the main issue is still there